# Replacing dots with commas on a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, replace

I'm using the code bellow to collect some info:

```
df = (
  df
  .select(
        date_format(date_trunc('month', col("reference_date")), 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias("month"),
        col("id"),
        col("name"),
        col("item_type"),
        col("sub_group"),
        col("latitude"),
        col("longitude")
  )
```

My latitude and longitude are values with dots, like this: `-30.130307 -51.2060018`  but I must replace the dot for a comma. I've tried both .replace() and .regexp_replace() but none of them are  working. Could you guys help me please?

Comment: "None of them are working", so what happens?

Comment: When I use .replace() like this `col("longitude").replace('.', ',')` I got this error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: And when I use `df = df.withColumn('new_latitude', regexp_replace('latitude', '.', ','))`, for example, all my characters turn into commas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the following dataframe as an example.

```
df.show()
+-------------------+-------------------+                                       
|           latitude|          longitude|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|  85.70708380916193| -68.05674981929877|
| 57.074495803252404|-42.648691976080215|
|  2.944303748172473| -62.66186439333423|
| 119.76923402031701|-114.41179457810185|
|-138.52573939229234|  54.38429596238362|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

You should be able to use `spark.sql` functions like the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df = df.withColumn("longitude", functions.regexp_replace('longitude',r'[.]',","))
df = df.withColumn("latitude", functions.regexp_replace('latitude',r'[.]',","))
df.show()
+-------------------+-------------------+
|           latitude|          longitude|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|  85,70708380916193| -68,05674981929877|
| 57,074495803252404|-42,648691976080215|
|  2,944303748172473| -62,66186439333423|
| 119,76923402031701|-114,41179457810185|
|-138,52573939229234|  54,38429596238362|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

`df_1= df.select('col1', 'col2').withColumn('col3', regexp_replace('col2', '\.', ','))`

so you need to use \ before .